# Firebase update() method deleting sub child nodes php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following set of object generated in back-end Php, And pushed into Firebase initially.

[image]

Here `status` key pair will be added by mobile app after the initial level push from backend.

Similarly I have the same set of keys and pair in `foors/0/` node. Inside the `floors` also the `status` key pair will be created by the mobile app.

[image: IMAGE 2]

I use update() function from the backed to update the latest values, Point to note here is I will not have the `status` key from the backed.

```
$value = [
   "fk_client_id" => "57",
   "fk_project_id" => "20"
    "is_synced" => "1",
    "floors" => [
        "fk_client_id" => "57",
        "fk_project_id" => "20",
        "floor_name" => "RBs - 1"
        ... // except status key pair. rest of the values are same
        ]
    ];
                    
$this->database->getReference('towerids/0/')->update($value);
```

The above update operation works perfectly and also It doesn't disturb the `status` node of `towerids/0/status` but the problem is it deletes the `floors/0/status` key pair.

I need to call the `'towerids/0/floors/0'` ref update() first and then I need to call 'towerids/0/' update() to make this process work.

But I have lot of similar status keys on sub children notes. By above method It is a time taking process to write multiple update operation for each references. Is there any solution to sort out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase's multi-path update function as follows:

1. Take all top-level keys from the dictionary/map.
2. Perform a set on the key/subpath specified in there.

Since you specify `floors` in the dictionary, the entire value under `floors` in your database gets replaced. So other top-level keys that you don't specify will be left at their current value, but all of `floors` will be replaced with the value in your call.

If you want to replace/write specific subkeys, specify the paths to those in your call. So something like:

```
$value = [
   "fk_client_id" => "57",
   "fk_project_id" => "20"
    "is_synced" => "1",
    "floors/fk_client_id" => "57",
    "floors/fk_project_id" => "20",
    "floors/floor_name" => "RBs - 1",
]
```

With *this* structure you specify the full subpath of each key to update, and Firebase will leave the other keys under `floors` unmodified.