# Kreait Firebase Database unable to delete child on Production

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-realtime-database

I follow this link in order to delete a child on Realtime Firebase.
https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/realtime-database.html#delete-data

It work's in localhost (my local dev environment) but when I put the website on production (using shared hosting) it doesn't work.

I can write with push() method new child, I can read also, but I cannot delete them.

In my Laravel(8) Controller I have something like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $factory = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount('./../firebase-realtime-database-credentials.json')
        ->withDatabaseUri('https://myAppName-xxxxxxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/');


    $database = $factory->createDatabase();

    /* Comment for the line below: in production, I have to put "/node" instead of just 
    "node". If not Laravel fire an Exception saying that a path shall start with "/" or be empty. */
    
    $myRef = $database->getReference("node"); 
}

public function myMethod($key) 
{
    // When this line is executed no error is fired by Laravel, and the child of remains intact.
    $queueRef->getChild($key)->remove();
}
```

My rules on Firebase-Realtime-Database is set up as:

```
{
   "rules": {
   ".read": "true",
   ".write": "true",
  
   "node": {
    ".indexOn": ["priority", "sent", ".value"]            
   }
  }
}
```

Please anybody can help with this issue? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Hi guys, I **SOLVED** the problem based on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68071866/firebase-update-method-deleting-sub-child-nodes-php), when @frank-van-puffelen said
 `$this->database->getReference('towerids/0/')->update($value);`. So, my line of code to delete a child on **Firebase-Database** from my Laravel (8) app is `$this->database->getReference("/node/".$child_key)->remove();`. **$child_key** can be grabed from a **for loop** over the database. Please be aware that in Laravel the path shall start with a _slash_ or be _empty_

Comment: That sounds like the start of a great self-answer @ack2v!   Posting it as an answer makes it more likely that future visitors will find it (most people don't read comments here), and also makes it clear to the system that there is a solution.

Comment: Thank's for your kindly words @frank-van-puffelen.